# Cannot import category_encoders module

Tags: python, encoding, data-science, categorical-data

I am not able to import [category_encoders](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/) module in jupyter notebook in python 3 virtual environment.

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-86725efc8d1e> in <module>()
      9 from plotly import graph_objs
     10 from datetime import datetime
---> 11 import category_encoders as ce
     12 
     13 import sklearn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'category_encoders'
```

Output of "which pip"

```
/opt/virtual_env/py3/bin/pip
```

Output of "pip show category_encoders" is

```
Name: category-encoders
Version: 1.3.0
Summary: A collection sklearn transformers to encode categorical variables as numeric
Home-page: https://github.com/wdm0006/categorical_encoding
Author: Will McGinnis
Author-email: will@pedalwrencher.com
License: BSD
Location: /opt/virtual_env/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: numpy, pandas, statsmodels, scikit-learn, patsy, scipy
Required-by:
```

Output of "pip list"

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
absl-py             0.7.0  
astor               0.7.1  
backcall            0.1.0  
category-encoders   1.3.0  
cycler              0.10.0
```

Comment: In case you are using anaconda, please install the package using conda install category-encoders. Restart jupyter. Then try the code.

Comment: I am not using anaconda right now.

Comment: Please restart jupyter and try to execute. Most of the times,  it will solve the problem.

Comment: i installed, and restarted the kernel many times, but still this error. I am sure i have pip installed it and scikit. I am using pycharm.

Answer (score 10):

`pip install --upgrade category_encoders`

Now,
Restart your kernel

`import category_encoders as...` so on and so forth

Also,
you can checkout the sk-learn's preprocessing class CategoricalEncoder...

`from sklearn.preprocessing import CategoricalEncoder`

get sk-learn from here,

`pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`

or Simply

`pip install sklearn`

Answer (score 1):

I was using anaconda environment.

Initially, I installed `category_encoders` using pip (within the conda enviornment) and it failed to resolve. Then I uninstalled ``category_encoders` from pip

`pip uninstall category-encoders`

and installed it using conda:

`conda install -c conda-forge category_encoders`

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have given your virtual environment ('py3' for your case) the permission for accessing the system site-packages directory you can try installing the package to your base (root) environment.

Search 'pyvenv.cfg' file in your system and check if it includes:

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

If yes, install the package to your root environment as stated [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders) and try importing it again in your Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cell above and type `! pip install --upgrade category_encoders`

It will install the package without opening a terminal window.